# How to compare two group means with multiple measures

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, mixed-model, random-effects-model

Suppose we have $N$ patients and two groups. For each patient, he can have one or two measures. Theses measures are classified by the group. Therefore one patient can contribute to both groups. 
  My purpose is to compare the difference between the group means. However, there exist correlation across the multiple measures for each patient, so the group means are correlated. I want to use the mixed effect model:

$Y_{ij}=Group_{ij}*\beta$ + $Group_{ij}*U_i$ + $\epsilon_{ij}$

Where Group is a 1 by 2 design matrix and $U_i$ is a vector with two random variables, $var(U_i)$=[$\sigma_{ij}$], $U_i$ and $\epsilon_{ij}$ are i.i.d.. Therefore

$cov(Y_{i1},Y_{i2'})=\sigma_{Group_1,Group_2}$

and

$cov(Y_{ij},Y_{i'j'})=0$

I've tried to use SAS and R to fit the above model. However SAS will give me "Did not converge" and R will say "the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable"

Here is my R code for simulation:

```
getdata<-function(n){
  set.seed(1)
  groupMean=c(1,2)
  data=c()
  sig=matrix(data=c(1,0.5,0.5,1),nrow = 2)
  for(i in 1:n){
    rndEffect=mvrnorm(1,c(0,0),sig)
    repeatNum=sample(1:2,1)
    for(j in 1:repeatNum){
      group=sample(1:2,1)
      y=groupMean[group]+rndEffect[group]+rnorm(1)
      data=rbind(data,c(y,group,i))
    }

  }
  data=as.data.frame(data)
  names(data)=c("y","group","id")
  data$group=as.factor(data$group)
  return(data)
}

mydata=getdata(10)
model <- lmer(y ~ group-1 + (0+group|id),mydata)
```

I know there are several existing answers related to this question, but none of them can solve my problem, the most related one is here:

[How to compare two sides of patients with multiple measures per patient?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95676/how-to-compare-two-sides-of-patients-with-multiple-measures-per-patient)

Unfortunately, their suggestion is the same as mine and the answer doesn't have the model or the code.